# I have a string in perl, how do I replace it with the same string but with [ ] around only the numbers?

Tags: regex, perl

Example: DATA500 replaced with DATA[500]

Comment: This isn't how StackOverflow works. You don't just post your homework here for us to write for you. You post code that isn't working how you want it to and we help you find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

This should work. It replaces groups of one or more digits, the "\d+" part, with the captured string surrounded by [], the "[$1]" part.

```
$a = "bob123bob123";

$a =~ s/(\d+)/[$1]/g;

print "$a";
# bob[123]bob[123]
```